# private scope for long blocks

Tags: macros, syntax, scoping

I understand that a privately-scoped block is created by squiggly-brace pairs (`{`, `}`).

The following document has body text "bar baz":

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\foo}{baz}
{  
  \renewcommand{\foo}{bar}
  \foo
}
\foo
\end{document}
```

If the scoped region is very long, then the brace pair may seem syntactically awkward.  Is a preferred method available for creating scoped blocks  of long sequences of text?

Comment: an environment is the normal way but it's not normal to just have a generic scope thing it is normally introduced for some reason eg `\begin{mything}...\end{mything}` even if the definition of the mything env is essentially empty. If you really do just want the grouping then i'd use `\begingroup`  `\endgroup`

Comment: It seems that  I simply would want to use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Then, just to verify... a group of this type is exactly equivalent to an environment, except for whatever further commands the environment definition might include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the preferred method very much depends on the circumstances. Three options come to mind:

- Define an environment. This is the preferred approach when the changes you want to make affect how something is typeset, e.g. because the content of the environment is a different type of text (or other content) than the surrounding one.
- Use explicit grouping using braces or `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. Both have exactly the same scoping behavior, but the more verbose `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` commands are a bit clearer and should be preferred for long portions of text.

  Note that explicitly redefining macros in the middle of the document somewhat goes against the LaTeX concept of separating content from design and can be considered bad style in general. As an exception, it can be okay, generally though you should "hide" the redefinition in a semantically named macro in the preamble.
- Sometimes, implementing the change you want to make as switches rather than begin-end pairs is the fitting choice, like the font switches or `\@makeatletter` and `\@makeatother`. If the switch only changes local definitions, you can still restrict its effect by enclosing it in a group using one of the options above.

In my experience, when you want to "change something for a long block of text", there should usually be an environment involved. Either a designated environment doing what you want, or a macro that will always be used inside of environments anyway (e.g. in a `table` or `tikzpicture`).

---

To answer your question if an `\begingroup`-`\endgroup` pair is exactly equivalent to an environment: Regarding scoping, it is. `\begin{foo}` just expands to `\begingroup` with some bookkeeping followed by `\foo`. `\end{foo}` expands to `\endfoo` followed by `\endgroup` with some bookkeeping.

Comment: So an existing environment `\foo` can be made into an environment simply by defining an empty `\endfoo`?

Comment: @epl Yes. Actually, an existing command `\foo` can just be used as an environment without further setup, because `\end{foo}` doesn't complain if `\endfoo` is undefined. This is against LaTeX syntax style, though, and may be confusing. It is therefore considered bad practice.

Comment: If there will be something within the scope that changes font size (for example), be careful to end with `\par` or a blank line; otherwise there may be a surprise when the baselines (for example) aren't what is expected.